# why console.dir(add); not showing scope variable? Windows 7

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scope, closures

```
const add = (function () {let counter = 0; return function () {counter += 1; return counter}}) ();
```

In windows 7 chrome console when i console.dir variable 'add' it does not show scope in it but in windows 10 it shows. why?

Comment: How do you run javascript using windows?

Comment: i write it straight into console (about:blank page)

Comment: windows 7 is outdated or what?

Comment: I guess that you are using a browser, nodejs, deno or bun.js -which one is it?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome console and node js is installed

Comment: Do you use the same version of chrome on both systems?

Comment: If someone has windows 7 can u plz check that code in your console?

Comment: both systems ? what does that even mean???

Comment: I mean `windows 7` and `windows 10`. The operating system shouldn't matter at all. It's all depend of browser's version

Comment: aa on Windows 10 ? I did not check that

Comment: U think i need to update chrome?

Comment: To get future Google Chrome updates, you'll need Windows 10 or later. This computer is using Windows 7. Learn more
Version 108.0.5359.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)